# Textview has no width in RelativeLayout between 2 images

Tags: android, width, textview, android-relativelayout

I have a relativelayout with an image, textview, image in that order.  I have the left image with parent align left turned on.  The right image has parent align right turned on.  And the textview with align center parent turned on.  The problem is that while everything is technically aligned correctly, the textview, while containing a value, has been reduced to basically a vertical line in the middle of the layout.  Why isn't the textview keeping its width based on its content?  Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></ImageView>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text=" sdfsdf sdhfhskdhfkh hsdkfhksdhfh shdfkhsdkhfkjsdh fhskdfhksdhfjk sdfhsdkhfkjsdfhkhasdhfksa fsakhdfhsdfhkshdf skdhfkshdfk"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView01" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ImageView02"></TextView>
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This works, thanks!  A little disconcerting, however, because the text in the textview in the middle is shifted all the way over to the right image instead of centered.  But only in the designer view.  When it's installed on my phone, it's centered.  Makes me a little nervous...like I don't have control of it completely.

Comment: it may be the designer issue because in my designer view it was not overlapping the image.

Answer (score 1):

check the width of ur imageviews..set the width of those 3 things as 'wrap content'.